# JSON block in XQuery: Syntax

Tags: xml, json, post, neo4j, xquery

I'm an XQuery newbie, and I need to send the following JSON block through XQuery to query a database (Neo4j):

```
{
    "query" : "START root=node(id_number) MATCH (root)-[:RELATED_TO]->(x) RETURN x.firstName, x.lastName",
    "params" : {
        "id_number" : "1"
    }
}
```

So I tried:

```
let $payload := '{
    "query" : "START root=node(id_number) MATCH (root)-[:RELATED_TO]->(x) RETURN x.firstName, x.lastName",
    "params" : {
        "id_number" : "1"
    }
}'
```

I am receiving the following error:

> 400 Bad Request. The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax. 
>   Error type: XQuery Engine error. HTTP Error. Connection String: .

I also tried interchanging " with ' and vice-versa, but obtained the same error.

What is the correct syntax for passing a JSON block in XQuery?

Any advice would be appreciated!

## ======================UPDATE======================

I switched to the Zorba XQuery Processor, but am still running into problems passing the JSON query. I have the following:

```
import module namespace json = 'http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/json';
import module namespace zorba-rest = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/zorba/rest-functions";
declare copy-namespaces no-preserve, no-inherit;

let $jsonresult := zorba-rest:post("http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
    <payload content-type="multipart/form-data">
        <part name="query">START root=node(1) MATCH (root)-[:RELATED_TO]->(x) RETURN x.firstName, x.lastName</part>
    </payload>,
    <headers>
        <header name="Accept">application/json; charset=UTF-8</header>
        <header name="Content-Type">application/json</header>
    </headers>)

let $result := json:parse($jsonresult)

return
<Table>
    <Row>
        <result>{
            $result
        }</result>
    </Row>
</Table>
```

I luckily run into no errors this time, however I get returned an empty dataset (there should be 4 returned rows):

```
<Table>
  <Row>
    <result>
      <json type="object" />
    </result>
  </Row>
</Table>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: The string is valid. How are you submitting the request? What XQuery processor are you using?

Comment: Is that let expression all you sent? you need a return after it. If this isn't all of your code, please post the complete XQuery expression.

Comment: Please look at the updated post – thank you!

Comment: I would recommend to use the EXPath HTTP Client: http://www.zorba.io/documentation/latest/modules/expath/http instead of the Zorba one.